# Пример показывающий эффективность применения ссылок

Tags: c++

Всем известно, что ссылки `(int & a = b)` в с++ имеют полезность при передаче больших объектов в качестве параметра в функцию, пример:

```
SomeType & f(SomeType & obj)
{ 
  return obj;
}
```

Всем понятно, что если `&` в параметрах не ставить, то создадудтся лишнии копии объектов, следовательно при больших размерах объекта память будет в пустую заниматься этими временными объектами.

Необходимо привести пример (связанный или не связанный с примером функции не важно), который показывал бы другую сторону эффективности ссылок в с++, в котором функции не используются вообще.

Вопрос задан на собеседовании на который я не ответил. У кого какие идеи?

спасибо

Comment: Ссылка в принципе «равносильна» указателю. Отсюда и вытекают все возможные применения. Например, вы можете вернуть новое значение переменной, переданной по ссылке, из функции.

Comment: > необходимо привести пример в с++, в котором функции не используются вообще.

Чего уж мелочиться? Давайте пойдем дальше: пример, где не используется c++ :)

Comment: @Flammable я вас понимаю, вопрос немного нестандартный, но надо именно использовать с++ в примере в котором функции не используюся, но применение ссылок оправдано их эффективностью

Comment: на собеседовании я начал говорить что ссылки эффективны при работе с функциями, и на это мне сказали приведи пример в котором нету функций но есть эффективность применения ссылок ))

Comment: Если нужен пример без функций, возьмите создание alias'а переменной: http://ideone.com/dlY03E

Comment: @VladD этот пример понятен, надо было что нибудь по сложнее как я понял

Comment: @arammis: Ну вот чуть сложнее: http://ideone.com/ZstKxR

Comment: @VladD да, спасибо, видимо надо было новый стандарт применить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хмм, Можно создать ограниченный массив, используя ссылочный тип в качестве значения, возвращаемого функции. Ограниченный массив - достаточно полезная вещь, т.к. при выполнении с++ кода проверка нарушения границ при индексировании массивов не предусмотрена. Это черевато выходом выходом за границы области памяти, выделенной для массива. Ниже приведу код ограниченного массива.

```
// Простой способ организации безопасного массива.

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int &put(int i); // Помещаем значение в массив.
int get(int i); // Считываем значение из массива.

int vals[10];
int error = -1;

int main()
{
   　put(0) = 10; // Помещаем значения в массив.
   　put(1) = 20;
   　put(9) = 30;

   　cout << get(0) << ' ';
   　cout << get(1) << ' ';
   　cout << get(9) << ' ';

   　// А теперь специально генерируем ошибку.

   　put(12) = 1; // Индекс за пределами границ массива.

    return 0;
}

// Функция занесения значения в массив.
int &put(int i)
{
　   if(i>=0 && i<10)
　　　     return vals[i]; // Возвращаем ссылку на i-й элемент.
　  　else {
　　　     cout << "Ошибка нарушения границ!\n";
　　　     return error; // Возвращаем ссылку на error.
　　  }
}

// Функция считывания значения из массива.
int get(int i)
{
　   if(i>=0 && i<10)
　　　     return vals[i]; // Возвращаем значение i-го элемента.
  　　else {
　　　     cout << "Ошибка нарушения границ!\n";
　　　     return error; // Возвращаем значение переменной error.
　　  }
}
```

Результат, полученный при выполнении этой программы, выглядит так.

> 10 20 30 Ошибка нарушения границ!

Надеюсь смог помочь ._.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <cstdio>
struct Animal{
virtual void talk() = 0 ;
};
struct Dog:Animal{
    void talk(){ printf("Wow-wow! \n"); };
};
int main()
{
    Dog barry;
    Animal& pet = barry;
    pet.talk(); //обращаемся к методу наследника по ссылке на предка.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну тут даже если указатель будет вместо ссылки всё равно приведение не произойдет )

Comment: Вы хотели показать пример **не**эффективного использования ссылок? Для проверки типов лучше использовать `dynamic_cast` с указателями и не использовать исключения для ситуации, не являющейся по сути исключительной.

Comment: грешен, грешен, поторопился. Конечно, во втором случае должно приводить ссылку базового класса к ссылке дочернего.

По теме: вероятно, от соискателя хотели услышать про возможность ссылочного полиморфизма.

Comment: @vladimir_: Угу, вполне может быть. В любом случае, подобные нечёткие вопросы всегда опасны.

Comment: этот нечеткий вопрос был мне задан на собеседовании, но ответившим здесь в любом случае спасибо

Comment: @arammis: вопрос, который вам достался, и в самом деле плохой, так как «эффективность» — весьма расплывчатое понятие. Эффективность по сравнению с **чем**? С кодом без ссылок? Ну так точно такого же по производительности эффекта можно всегда добиться с одними лишь указателями. Поэтому, строго говоря, вопрос некорректен. Но чтобы ответить прямо так на интервью, надо иметь здоровый пофигизм, готовность к дискуссии и хорошие фактические знания.

Comment: @arammis, ссылки это одна из самых неудачных концепций крестов, эффективно все запутывающая.


    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
      int a = 10;
      int &ra = a, &rr = a, *p;
      
      cout << "&a:" << &a << " a=" << a << " ra=" << ra << " rr=" << rr << '\n';
    
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int b = i + 20;
        rr = b;
        p = &b;
      }
    
      cout << "&a:" << &a << " a=" << a << " ra=" << ra << " rr = " << rr 
           << " p = " << p << ": " << *p << '\n';
    

...

(места мало)

Comment: (продолжение)

...

      ra = 30;
      cout << "&a:" << &a << " a=" << a << " ra=" << ra << " rr = " << rr 
           << " p = " << p << ": " << *p << '\n';
    }
  

А теперь выбросьте печать `a` и `&a`, добавьте пару десятков строк кода  и попробуйте разобраться.

Comment: @VladD я не говорил что вопрос хороший, его суть была в том, чтобы разобраться что хотели от меня услышать люди которые вели собеседование, что я и сделал, в некотором смысле. еще раз всем спасибо